# C++ template binary search tree - Argument list error

Tags: c++, templates, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

What I want is a rather simple binary search tree that via the template tag, allows for any numerical data to be used within it, but I'm having some rather obnoxious issues that I have no clue of how to get rid off, if anyone can help, it would be much appreciated. The error message that keeps popping up for me is "Invalid use of template-name 'BST' without an argument list" - and quite frankly I have no clue how to solve it. It occurs on line 31, 89, 105, 120, 130, 141 in the bst.cpp file. Given that I'm not as proficient when it comes to binary search trees, I'd prefer as conclusive of an answer as possible (even going as far as to mention exactly where and what needs to be changed):

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bst.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    BST <int> tree;
    tree.insert(8);
    tree.insert(25);
    tree.insert(99);
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.insert(25);
    tree.insert(20);
    tree.insert(2);
    tree.insert(89);
    tree.insert(15);
    tree.insert(10);
    tree.insert(30);
    tree.insert(50);
    tree.displayorder();



    int number;

    int Inputnumber;
    while (true){
        cout << "Choose what you want to do: " << endl << "1# Insert" << endl << "2# Display Orders" << endl <<  "3# Search" << endl << "4# Delete" << endl << endl << endl;
        cin >> Inputnumber;
        if (Inputnumber==1){
            cout << endl << "Enter the number you want inserted: ";
            cin >> number;
            tree.insert(number);
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }
        if (Inputnumber==2){
            cout<<"Display Orders: " << endl;
            tree.displayorder();
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }

        if (Inputnumber==3){
            cout<<"Enter the number you want to search for: ";
            cin >> number;
            tree.search(number);
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }
        if (Inputnumber==4){
            cout << "Enter the number you want to remove: ";
            cin >> number;
            tree.remove(number);
            cout << endl << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

**BST.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bst.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void BST<T>::preorder(node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL){
        return;
    }
    cout << tree->data << " ";
    inorder(tree->left);
    inorder(tree->right);
}



template <class T>
void BST<T>::postorder(node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL){
        return;
    }
    inorder(tree->left);
    inorder(tree->right);
    cout << tree->data << " ";
}

template <typename T>
BST::node* BST<T>::find(node* tree, T x)        //ERROR HERE
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(x < tree->data)
        return find(tree->left, x);
    else if(x > tree->data)
        return find(tree->right, x);
    else
        return tree;
}
template <typename T>
BST<T>::BST()
{
    root = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
BST<T>::~BST()
{
    root = makeEmpty(root);
}

template <class T>
void BST<T>::insert(T x)
{
    root = insert(x, root);
}

template <class T>
void BST<T>::remove(T x)
{
    root = remove(x, root);
}

template <class T>
void BST<T>::displayorder()
{
    inorder(root);
    cout << endl;
    preorder(root);
    cout << endl;
    postorder(root);
    cout << endl << endl;
}

template <class T>
void BST<T>::search(T x)
{
    if(root = find(root, x)){
        cout << endl << "Found!" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << endl << "Not Found!" << endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
BST::node* BST<T>::makeEmpty(node* tree)        //ERROR HERE
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    {
        makeEmpty(tree->left);
        makeEmpty(tree->right);
        delete tree;
    }
    return NULL;
}




template <class T>
BST::node* BST<T>::insert(T x, node* tree)      //ERROR HERE
{
    if(tree == NULL)
    {
        tree = new node;
        tree->data = x;
        tree->left = tree->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(x < tree->data)
        tree->left = insert(x, tree->left);
    else if(x >= tree->data)
        tree->right = insert(x, tree->right);
    return tree;
}

BST::node* BST::findMin(node* tree)             //ERROR HERE
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(tree->left == NULL)
        return tree;
    else
        return findMin(tree->left);
}

BST::node* BST::findMax(node* tree)             //ERROR HERE
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(tree->right == NULL)
        return tree;
    else
        return findMax(tree->right);
}

template <typename T>
BST::node* BST<T>::remove(T x, node* tree)      //ERROR HERE
{
    node* temp;
    if(tree == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(x < tree->data)
        tree->left = remove(x, tree->left);
    else if(x > tree->data)
        tree->right = remove(x, tree->right);
    else if(tree->left && tree->right)
    {
        temp = findMin(tree->right);
        tree->data = temp->data;
        tree->right = remove(tree->data, tree->right);
    }
    else
    {
        temp = tree;
        if(tree->left == NULL)
            tree = tree->right;
        else if(tree->right == NULL)
            tree = tree->left;
        delete temp;
    }

    return tree;
}

template <class T>
void BST<T>::inorder(node* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL){
        return;
    }
    inorder(tree->left);
    cout << tree->data << " ";
    inorder(tree->right);
}
```

**BST.h**

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H


template <class T>
class BST
{
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;

    node* makeEmpty(node* tree);

    node* insert(T x, node* tree);

    node* findMin(node* tree);

    node* findMax(node* tree);

    node* remove(T x, node* tree);

    void inorder(node* tree);

    void preorder(node* tree);



    void postorder(node* tree);


public:
    BST();

    ~BST();


    node* find(node* tree, T x);

    void insert(T x);

    void remove(T x);

    void displayorder();

    void search(T x);
};

#endif // BST_H
```

Comment: You should probably take some time to read [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) Will save you from asking another question related to this code again soon.

Comment: You know std::set?

Answer (score 3):

By example, in

```
BST::node* BST<T>::find(node* tree, T x)
```

you forget the `<T>` component for the first `BST`.

Should be

```
// vvv
BST<T>::node* BST<T>::find(node* tree, T x)
```

All other errors are of the same type.

Answer (score 3):

A class template like the `BST` you are apparently using is not a type. It's a recipe for creating a class type.  What the error message is trying to tell you is that (almost) anywhere you use the name `BST`, you need to supply template arguments immediately after it inside `<`angle brackets`>`.

For example, in

```
template <class T>
BST::node* BST<T>::makeEmpty(node* tree)        //ERROR HERE
```

the compiler is complaining about the first instance of `BST` in the return type, not the one that correctly specifies `BST<T>` as the class type.  This should probably be:

```
template <class T>
BST<T>::node* BST<T>::makeEmpty(node* tree)
```

[There are at least two exceptions to this general rule.  One is that the name of a template alone can be used as a template argument to another template which expects a template instead of a type or value.

The other is called the "injected class name": Inside the scope of a class template, including a class template member, you can use just the name of the template as an alias to the "current" specialization.

So in fact you could also use a trailing return type and do:

```
template <class T>
auto BST<T>::makeEmpty(node* tree) -> BST::node*
```

In the above, since the return type now comes after the `BST<T>::` and not before, it is now in the scope of the class template, so you are allowed to use just `BST` as an alias for `BST<T>`.]